# Mean squared error of 2 distributions when there are many zero values

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, error, histogram

I am comparing two (2-D) distributions using mean squared error. **I take the difference between distributions, square them, average them and multiply them by the area of a pixel/bin.** These distributions represent the receptive field of a neuron, so are mostly zeros surrounding a 2-D Gaussian.

The problem I have is that as I decrease the binsize of my distributions the number of bins containing zero increases, as a result the mean squared error of bins decreases, even though the underlying distributions themselves have not changed.

I would like to compare errors across different binsizes, so is there a way to correct MSE when there are many zeros? Or is there a way to correct for binsize that I have missed? Or is there a better approach I could use?

Comment: Your problem statement lacks clarity. How do you measure *error*? How do you take "the difference between distributions"? What is the purpose of this analysis? If you are working with two bivariate normal distributions (with known? or estimated? parameters) what's the point of the binning?

Comment: I measure error using mean squared error. I get the difference by subtracting one distribution from the other. I know the parameters for one distribution but not the second - I want to know how well the second fits the first. The binning is because the first distribution is a probability distribution but the second is a list of observations (x,y points) which need to be binned into a bivariate histogram.